# How to join DataFrames and take the newest row by timestamp?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two PySpark DataFrames. I join both DataFrames as follows:

```
df = df1.join(df2,['col1', 'col2'], 'inner')
```

The DataFrame `df2` has a column `timestamp`, while `df1` does not have it:

```
df1 =
col1   col2
AA     11
BB     22

df2 =
timestamp    col1   col2  col3
1510586134   AA     11    3
1510586140   AA     11    2
1510586200   AA     11    5
1510586134   BB     22    3
```

How can I join DataFrames by the newest row of `df2` according to `timestamp`?

The result should be the following:

```
col1   col2   col3
AA     11     5
BB     22     3
```

Comment: Use window functions to geta dataframe with the newest row. `Window.partitionBy("col1", "col2").orderBy("timestamp")` and then join the resultant dataframe with `col1, col2` as the key.

Comment: @philantrovert: .orderBy(col("timestam").desc()? Sould I use `where` after `orderBy` in order to take the newest one?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rank
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

#sample data
df1 = sc.parallelize([
    ['AA', 11],
    ['BB', 22]
]).toDF(('col1', 'col2'))
df2 = sc.parallelize([
    [1510586134, 'AA', 11, 3],
    [1510586140, 'AA', 11, 2],
    [1510586200, 'AA', 11, 5],
    [1510586134, 'BB', 22, 3]
]).toDF(('timestamp', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'))

#select latest row of df2 according to timestamp
df2_temp = df2.withColumn('timestamp_format_col', col('timestamp').cast("timestamp"))
window = Window.partitionBy('col1','col2').\
    orderBy(col('timestamp_format_col').desc())
df2_temp = df2_temp.\
    select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')).\
    filter(col('rank')==1).\
    drop('rank','timestamp','timestamp_format_col')

#final result
df = df1.join(df2_temp, ['col1', 'col2'], 'inner')
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  BB|  22|   3|
|  AA|  11|   5|
+----+----+----+
```